# My Server/Listener lacks True Grit

Tags: c#, sockets

My Server/Listener has ADD or no stamina; what is the antidote or prodote?

The app serves as both ends of a socket communication. It seems to work fine for the first message (I enter "Bla" in textBox1, and label1 then reads "Bla back atcha" , but it fails on subsequent messages. I have one instance of the app running on my dev machine, and another instance (renamed to include the word "Server") on another machine.

I've pasted the code below, and the err msg I get on my second attempt to send a message ("No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.24.93.110:51111").

When I start the "Server" instance on the other machine and run "netstat -a" in a command line, it says that the server machine is LISTENING to my dev machine on port 51111.

After the first message is passed, and apparently received and tossed back, running "netstat -a" still shows a connection to my dev machine, but that status is no longer LISTENING but TIME_WAIT.

And then, I try passing another message, and I get the err msg (Exhibit B below)

EXHIBIT A: Source

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string sJerrysIPAddr = "10.24.31.110";
        string sMyIPAddr = "10.24.31.128";
        string sThisAppFileName = string.Empty;
        bool bThisInstanceFunctionsAsServer = false;

        internal static Form1 MainSocketPairForm = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainSocketPairForm = this;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sThisAppFileName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
            lblFileName.Text = sThisAppFileName;

            // Client and Server code are here combined in one app; however, we want each instance to run as
            // just one or the other, so (the .exe functioning as a Server should be renamed with the subString
            // "Server" somewhere in the filename):
            bThisInstanceFunctionsAsServer = sThisAppFileName.Contains("Server");
            if (bThisInstanceFunctionsAsServer)
            {
                new Thread(Server).Start();       // Run server method concurrently.
                Thread.Sleep(500);                // Give server time to start.
            }
            btnSendMsg.Visible = !bThisInstanceFunctionsAsServer;
        }

        static void Client()
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(Form1.MainSocketPairForm.sJerrysIPAddr, 51111)) // err here second time 
            using (NetworkStream n = client.GetStream())
            {
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
                w.Write(Form1.MainSocketPairForm.textBox1.Text.ToString());
                w.Flush();
                Form1.MainSocketPairForm.label1.Text = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
            }
        }

        static void Server()     // Handles a single client request, then exits.
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 51111);
            listener.Start(); //Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
            // got the above err msg with an instance running and listening on jerry's machine
            // continues to listen even after shut down...
            using (TcpClient c = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
            using (NetworkStream n = c.GetStream())
            {
                string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
                w.Write(msg + " back atcha!");
                w.Flush(); // Must call Flush because we're not disposing the writer.
            }
            listener.Stop();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Client();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

EXHIBIT B: Full Error Message

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
>     Message="No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.24.93.110:51111"
>     Source="System"
>     ErrorCode=10061
>     NativeErrorCode=10061
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
>          at testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell.Form1.Client() in 
>   C:\testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell\testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell\Form1.cs:line 57
>          at testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell\testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell\Form1.cs:line 90 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, 
>   ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext 
>   context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell.Program.Main() in 
>   C:\testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell\testSocketSendAndReceive_Nutshell\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, 
>   Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You need to call `client.Close()` after sending the response.</del>  You <del>also</del> need a loop around the server's accept logic:

```
var shouldExit == false;
while (!shouldExit)
    using (TcpClient c = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
    {
        using (NetworkStream n = c.GetStream())
        {
            string msg = new BinaryReader(n).ReadString();
            if (msg == "exit")
                // Client told us to exit...
                shouldExit = true;
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(n);
            w.Write(msg + " back atcha!");
            w.Flush(); // Must call Flush because we're not disposing the writer.
        }
    }
```

This is all in the examples in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: There's no need to call `Close()` here - it's in a `using` statement, so it's being disposed automatically. The looping is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the comment at the start of your server code

```
static void Server()     // Handles a single client request, then exits.
```

It's exactly correct - you call `AcceptTcpClient` once, respond, and then shut down the listener. That will only handle a single connection. If you want it to handle more than one connection, you need to loop round - quite possibly handing off each TCP client to a separate thread before looping round and accepting again.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment on the `Server()` method answers your own question:

```
// Handles a single client request, then exits.
```

After you read the first string, you call `listener.Stop()` and then return from the function, so the thread exits.  If you want the server to stay alive for subsequent requests, you're going to have to incorporate some kind of loop.

Answer (score 2):

On your server, you are disposing the client after you receive the first message.

If you want to keep the TCP connection active, you will need to save the TCP client in the server method.  Then you can use methods like `client.GetStream().Read()` which will read the data out of the client.  Note that this method will block until you receive a message from the stream.

In order to handle n requests, you will have to do some kind of loop:

```
while(true) {
   string msg = client.GetStream().Read();
   // do something with the message
}
```

There are also async methods which will allow you to perform these actions on another thread.  Look into the `BeginRead()` method on the stream.